# R: Can't load XLConnectJars (32-bit R 32-bit Java)

Tags: r

I'm trying to get XLConnectJars to work, but every time I use library(XLConnectJars), I get the following message:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'XLConnectJars', details:
  call: .jcall(.rJava.class.loader, "V", "addClassPath", as.character(path))
  error: Java Exception <no description because toString() failed>.jcall(.rJava.class.loader, "V", "addClassPath", as.character(path))<S4 object of class "jobjRef">
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘XLConnectJars’
```

Any ideas of what's going on?

Comment: Don't use Java. Use the `readxl` package to read/write excel files.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a dependency of XLConnect, and you'll get that error if you haven't downloaded it. You can get it from www.java.com.